# ASP.NET MVC password validation with hash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, hash

So I want to add my Custom Hash into my password, but it got stuck because my own validation

**My Model:**

```
public class ms_user
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Input your Login Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public object user_id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Input your Password")]
    // Validation at least 1 uppercase & 1 number, password lenght must be greater then 6 and lower then 12, with no Special Character
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9](.{6,12})$", ErrorMessage = "Error, Wrong Password Format")] 
    public object password { get; set; }
}
```

Sample:

Password Inputed : **Admin123** // Pass Validation

HashedPassword Output: **l92Vi3c2Af7Oftgy7JqYJKR8isYXef8pIOqvMzjrN6rnRct6W6UuDzv0YRCOudPPXnC69Gj2J4igXZWH1WRz9C19abN4UWKSqX8d0TxA+0IvXJAvzoksaEWPQm56gy/l:9KZQeh3nB9apjy81V/FvfU** // After i hashed my password,

My Project pass the Password Validation, but on the db.SaveChanges(); it return error, because the Password validation

is there any solution?? i prefer not to add javascript validation...

Thx

Comment: What is the error it is throwing? What is the maximum allowed length of Password column in your User table? Looking at the length of the Hashed Password, it could be "validation failed for one or more entities".

Comment: validation error because the HashedPassword lenght is more then 12 character

Answer (score 0):

Change the Datatype of Password column to nvarchar(MAX) in your User table to accomodate the Hashed Password.

Comment: i've already done that, but the password length validation for password still exist, because the HashedPassword output will be in the Password Field in the database... So basically my problem is, when i type "Admin123" into the password form, they will pass thevalidation, but after my system hashed the password, the lenght will change and on db.SaveChanges() they will return error said the password format is wrong...

Comment: You have 2 seperate User view Model and Datamodel right? You add the regular expression validation to your User 'View Model'. After submitting, you verify inside your controller for the validation. 

Then pass the data to your Data model(entity), at which point you hash it using a function and call save changes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact same problem, because I updated the password length in database to nvarchar(max) but didn't update the model in visual studio after that. So **Update the Model** and it should fix that.

Comment: why this doesn't answer the question?